# boost libraries (v1.75 to 1.77) aren't fully generated by compilation

Tags: boost, compilation

I compiled boost library v1.75, v1.76 and v1.77 on ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04.

depending on whether I compile boost library on ubuntu 16.4 or 18.04 system, I don't obtain the same set of libraries.
Only 96 libraries are generated on ubuntu 16.04 against 123 on ubuntu 18.04.

Obviously, I need one missing library (libboost_json.a) on the ubuntu 16.04.

Below the list of the libraries generated on ubuntu 16.04 :

```
cmake                         libboost_filesystem.so               libboost_program_options.so              libboost_stacktrace_noop.so
libboost_atomic.a             libboost_filesystem.so.1.77.0        libboost_program_options.so.1.77.0       libboost_stacktrace_noop.so.1.77.0
libboost_atomic.so            libboost_graph.a                     libboost_python37.a                      libboost_system.a
libboost_atomic.so.1.77.0     libboost_graph.so                    libboost_python37.so                     libboost_system.so
libboost_chrono.a             libboost_graph.so.1.77.0             libboost_python37.so.1.77.0              libboost_system.so.1.77.0
libboost_chrono.so            libboost_iostreams.a                 libboost_random.a                        libboost_test_exec_monitor.a
libboost_chrono.so.1.77.0     libboost_iostreams.so                libboost_random.so                       libboost_thread.a
libboost_container.a          libboost_iostreams.so.1.77.0         libboost_random.so.1.77.0                libboost_thread.so
libboost_container.so         libboost_locale.a                    libboost_regex.a                         libboost_thread.so.1.77.0
libboost_container.so.1.77.0  libboost_locale.so                   libboost_regex.so                        libboost_timer.a
libboost_context.a            libboost_locale.so.1.77.0            libboost_regex.so.1.77.0                 libboost_timer.so
libboost_context.so           libboost_log.a                       libboost_serialization.a                 libboost_timer.so.1.77.0
libboost_context.so.1.77.0    libboost_log_setup.a                 libboost_serialization.so                libboost_type_erasure.a
libboost_contract.a           libboost_log_setup.so                libboost_serialization.so.1.77.0         libboost_type_erasure.so
libboost_contract.so          libboost_log_setup.so.1.77.0         libboost_stacktrace_addr2line.a          libboost_type_erasure.so.1.77.0
libboost_contract.so.1.77.0   libboost_log.so                      libboost_stacktrace_addr2line.so         libboost_unit_test_framework.a
libboost_coroutine.a          libboost_log.so.1.77.0               libboost_stacktrace_addr2line.so.1.77.0  libboost_unit_test_framework.so
libboost_coroutine.so         libboost_numpy37.a                   libboost_stacktrace_backtrace.a          libboost_unit_test_framework.so.1.77.0
libboost_coroutine.so.1.77.0  libboost_numpy37.so                  libboost_stacktrace_backtrace.so         libboost_wave.a
libboost_date_time.a          libboost_numpy37.so.1.77.0           libboost_stacktrace_backtrace.so.1.77.0  libboost_wave.so
libboost_date_time.so         libboost_prg_exec_monitor.a          libboost_stacktrace_basic.a              libboost_wave.so.1.77.0
libboost_date_time.so.1.77.0  libboost_prg_exec_monitor.so         libboost_stacktrace_basic.so             libboost_wserialization.a
libboost_exception.a          libboost_prg_exec_monitor.so.1.77.0  libboost_stacktrace_basic.so.1.77.0      libboost_wserialization.so
libboost_filesystem.a         libboost_program_options.a           libboost_stacktrace_noop.a               libboost_wserialization.so.1.77.0
```

Below the list of the libraries generated on ubuntu 18.04 :

```
cmake                          libboost_graph.so.1.77.0      libboost_math_tr1l.so.1.77.0             libboost_stacktrace_backtrace.so
libboost_atomic.a              libboost_iostreams.a          libboost_math_tr1.so                     libboost_stacktrace_backtrace.so.1.77.0
libboost_atomic.so             libboost_iostreams.so         libboost_math_tr1.so.1.77.0              libboost_stacktrace_basic.a
libboost_atomic.so.1.77.0      libboost_iostreams.so.1.77.0  libboost_nowide.a                        libboost_stacktrace_basic.so
libboost_chrono.a              libboost_json.a               libboost_nowide.so                       libboost_stacktrace_basic.so.1.77.0
libboost_chrono.so             libboost_json.so              libboost_nowide.so.1.77.0                libboost_stacktrace_noop.a
libboost_chrono.so.1.77.0      libboost_json.so.1.77.0       libboost_numpy27.a                       libboost_stacktrace_noop.so
libboost_container.a           libboost_locale.a             libboost_numpy27.so                      libboost_stacktrace_noop.so.1.77.0
libboost_container.so          libboost_locale.so            libboost_numpy27.so.1.77.0               libboost_system.a
libboost_container.so.1.77.0   libboost_locale.so.1.77.0     libboost_prg_exec_monitor.a              libboost_system.so
libboost_context.a             libboost_log.a                libboost_prg_exec_monitor.so             libboost_system.so.1.77.0
libboost_context.so            libboost_log_setup.a          libboost_prg_exec_monitor.so.1.77.0      libboost_test_exec_monitor.a
libboost_context.so.1.77.0     libboost_log_setup.so         libboost_program_options.a               libboost_thread.a
libboost_contract.a            libboost_log_setup.so.1.77.0  libboost_program_options.so              libboost_thread.so
libboost_contract.so           libboost_log.so               libboost_program_options.so.1.77.0       libboost_thread.so.1.77.0
libboost_contract.so.1.77.0    libboost_log.so.1.77.0        libboost_python27.a                      libboost_timer.a
libboost_coroutine.a           libboost_math_c99.a           libboost_python27.so                     libboost_timer.so
libboost_coroutine.so          libboost_math_c99f.a          libboost_python27.so.1.77.0              libboost_timer.so.1.77.0
libboost_coroutine.so.1.77.0   libboost_math_c99f.so         libboost_random.a                        libboost_type_erasure.a
libboost_date_time.a           libboost_math_c99f.so.1.77.0  libboost_random.so                       libboost_type_erasure.so
libboost_date_time.so          libboost_math_c99l.a          libboost_random.so.1.77.0                libboost_type_erasure.so.1.77.0
libboost_date_time.so.1.77.0   libboost_math_c99l.so         libboost_regex.a                         libboost_unit_test_framework.a
libboost_exception.a           libboost_math_c99l.so.1.77.0  libboost_regex.so                        libboost_unit_test_framework.so
libboost_fiber.a               libboost_math_c99.so          libboost_regex.so.1.77.0                 libboost_unit_test_framework.so.1.77.0
libboost_fiber.so              libboost_math_c99.so.1.77.0   libboost_serialization.a                 libboost_wave.a
libboost_fiber.so.1.77.0       libboost_math_tr1.a           libboost_serialization.so                libboost_wave.so
libboost_filesystem.a          libboost_math_tr1f.a          libboost_serialization.so.1.77.0         libboost_wave.so.1.77.0
libboost_filesystem.so         libboost_math_tr1f.so         libboost_stacktrace_addr2line.a          libboost_wserialization.a
libboost_filesystem.so.1.77.0  libboost_math_tr1f.so.1.77.0  libboost_stacktrace_addr2line.so         libboost_wserialization.so
libboost_graph.a               libboost_math_tr1l.a          libboost_stacktrace_addr2line.so.1.77.0  libboost_wserialization.so.1.77.0
libboost_graph.so              libboost_math_tr1l.so         libboost_stacktrace_backtrace.a
```

Hints would be quite appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On ubuntu 16.04, my compiler was :

```
(base) syl@WorkStation-T3500:~/tmp/boost_1_77_0$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609
```

This version didn't support necessary C++11 standards requirements.

I had to force the gcc "-std" option to C++14 through b2 :

```
 ./b2 cxxflags="-std=c++14"
```

Then all the libraries were compiled and properly generated.